# Android MP Chart lib scroll bar indicator on X and Y axis

Tags: android

com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
not able to add the scroll bar on x and y-axis 
can anyone help me out?

Comment: Use HorizontalScrollView for X-axis scrollbar

Comment: I think it already has zoom in out functionality. What you want to achieve?

Comment: I think when you zoom it automatically adds scrolling

Comment: My requirement is it should show scroll bar both the side x and y-axis even though I zoom out and zoom in scroll bar should adjust accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

- setVisibleXRangeMaximum(float maxXRange): Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. If this is e.g. set to 10, no more than 10 values on the x-axis can be viewed at once without scrolling.
- setVisibleXRangeMinimum(float minXRange): Sets the size of the area (range on the x-axis) that should be minimum visible at once. If this is e.g. set to 10, it is not possible to zoom in further than 10 values on the x-axis.
- setVisibleYRangeMaximum(float maxYRange, AxisDependency axis): Sets the size of the area (range on the y-axis) that should be maximum visible at once. You also need to provide the axis this constraint should apply to.

After that u will get scrolling in your chart on both of the axis. Question is not very clear but I think you are looking for that by fixing number of entries on a view and by scrolling user can see other values present in chart. If that is the case then use above methods. Hope It helps :) Happy Coding :). Do let me know if it works or if your requirement is different please do elaborate.

Comment: My requirement is it should show scroll bar both the side x and y-axis even though I zoom out and zoom in scroll bar should adjust accordingly.